# getting error when using -g in npm

Tags: node.js, npm

when I try to install any package globally, I get multiple errors. have a look at the image

[the errors in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htdpt.png)

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you share not the image, but text?

Comment: Did you use `sudoers` to install the package? For example: `sudo npm i -g anypackage`

Comment: You do NOT have the permission to do that. You have to have the correct access rights. In other words, use your Admin profile.

Comment: @Bigga_HD I'm using the admin user

Comment: Okay, so different OS. I see @Shablcu got you coverd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install any global package just add `sudo` prefix.  `sudo npm install -g express`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install packages globally with the "g"-parameter you must be root.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to just run `sudo npm install -g express` to successfully install [express](https://expressjs.com/).

But a long time solution for the permission access, run `chown -R YOUR_USERNAME /usr/lib/node_modules` from your terminal so that you will not have to include `sudo` in your subsequent installation using `-g`